# using awk insert new data and adding how far away

Tags: awk

i have a data set like this (file.txt) tab separated

```
1   a   
3   b
5   c
7   d
8   e
12  f
17  g
20  h
```

When i want to add a new data

```
6
```

I want to create new column which includes remaining from new entry.
Desired output is like that:

```
1   a   5   
3   b   3
5   c   1
6       0
7   d   1
8   e   2
12  f   6
17  g   11
20  h   14
```

I have tried:

```
awk -v new="6" '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
{gsub(new,",\n")}
{print $0"\n"$2,$3=|new-$1|}
' file
```

Comment: What if there already exists the same number? Add the new number after or before the existing one? Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: thanks your attention @JamesBrown If there is already same number, i want to add after from exist.

Comment: Does it have to be purely `awk`? It's a lot simpler breaking out to Bash: append the new line, sort, then use awk to add the 3rd column.

Comment: thanks for your attention @RuudHelderman . i choose awk for implement to my awk code pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v new=6 '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
    if((new<$1)&&f=="") {            # when greater than new values seen  
        print new                    # for the first time, act
        f=1                          # flag to print only once
    }
    print $1,$2,((v=new-$1)<0?-v:v)  # abs with ternary operator
}' file
```

Output:

```
1       a       5
3       b       3
5       c       1
6
7       d       1
8       e       2
12      f       6
17      g       11
20      h       14
```